# How to get this jQuery scrollTop() to work...?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Trying to get this script to work (basically want the user to scroll the html page I made, and when it reaches a certain point, to have the text change colour).

Here's what I've done so far:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
        if(jQuery(window).scrollTop() > 20){

            jQuery(".changeme").addClass("changeme2");

        }

    });
```

The css:

```
.changeme{
    height: 300px;
}

.changeme2{
    color: blue;
}
```

and the HTML:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Scroll effect</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js" integrity="sha256-Qw82+bXyGq6MydymqBxNPYTaUXXq7c8v3CwiYwLLNXU=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="scroll.js"></script>


</head>
<body>
    <div class="changeme">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</div>
    <div class="changeme">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</div>
    <div class="changeme">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Its something very simple, but I cant get it to work. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code is working perfectly but you are not detecting the document on the scroll, use below code snippet for reference.

```
<script>
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    jQuery(document).scroll(function(){
        if(jQuery(window).scrollTop() > 20){
            jQuery(".changeme").addClass("changeme2");
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

First, get an updated version of jQuery if you can. And the shorter `$` instead of `jQuery` can also make it much easier to use jQuery.

To do something when you interact with the page you should listen for *events*. In this case listen for the scroll event. You can listen for events with the [`on`](https://api.jquery.com/on/) method.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  let $window = $(window);
  let $changeMe = $('.changeme');

  $window.on('scroll', function() {
    if ($window.scrollTop() > 20) {
      $changeMe.addClass('changeme2');
    } else {
      $changeMe.removeClass('changeme2');
    }
  });

});
```

Comment: Thanks...was also wondering if theres a way to fade in .addClass("changeme2") in jQuery?

Comment: Look into CSS transitions. Give the `changeme` class an `opacity: 0` and `changeme2` an `opacity: 1`. Then by adding a transition property you can make the change in opacity gradual.